# Webcam immediately freezes opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, gesture

I am trying to build a gesture based mouse using webcam and I'm still in the process of perfecting the idea but I'm faced with a problem that my webcam freezes immediately upon opening. It happens with both spyder and anaconda prompt. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import wx
mouse=Controller()

app=wx.App(False)
(sx,sy)=wx.GetDisplaySize()
(camx,camy)=(320,240)


lowerBound=np.array([33,80,40])
upperBound=np.array([102,255,255])

cam= cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cam.set(3,camx)
cam.set(4,camy)

kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))
pinchFlag=0

while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()


    #convert BGR to HSV
    imgHSV= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # create the Mask
    mask=cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lowerBound,upperBound)
    #morphology
    maskOpen=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
    maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)

    maskFinal=maskClose
    conts,h=cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    if(len(conts)==2):
        if(pinchFlag==1):
            pinchFlag=0
            mouse.release(Button.left)
        x1,y1,w1,h1=cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
        x2,y2,w2,h2=cv2.boundingRect(conts[1])
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x1+w1,y1+h1),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x2,y2),(x2+w2,y2+h2),(255,0,0),2)
        cx1=int(x1+w1/2)
        cy1=int(y1+h1/2)
        cx2=int(x2+w2/2)
        cy2=int(y2+h2/2)
        cx=int((cx1+cx2)/2)
        cy=int((cy1+cy2)/2)
        cv2.line(img, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy),2,(0,0,255),2)
        mouseLoc=(sx-(cx*sx/camx), cy*sy/camy)
        mouse.position=mouseLoc 
        while mouse.position!=mouseLoc:
            pass
    elif(len(conts)==1):
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
        if(pinchFlag==0):
            pinchFlag=1
            mouse.press(Button.left)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        cx=int(x+w/2)
        cy=int(y+h/2)
        cv2.circle(img,(cx,cy),int((w+h)/4),(0,0,255),2)
        mouseLoc=(sx-(cx*sx/camx), cy*sy/camy)
        mouse.position=mouseLoc 
        while mouse.position!=mouseLoc:
            pass
    cv2.imshow("cam",img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have looked throughout the interent but didn't find any satisfactory answers that will solve my problem

Comment: It looks like you have a while loop at the end there that probably gets caught up forever. Instead of `pass`, try a `break` until you get your intended logic in there.

Comment: Thanks man. It started working after replacing the pass with break. But I still don't understand why the camera opens up as a minimized window